# Pylint error when inheriting from List[type]

Tags: python, pylint, typing

I wrote the following piece of code:

```
from typing import List

class Foo():
    def __init__(self, _a : int, _b : bool):
        self.a = _a
        self.b = _b

class Bar(List[Foo]):
    def print(self):
        for entry in self: # Non-iterable value self is used in an iterating contextpylint(not-an-iterable)
            print(entry.a)
            print(entry.b)

foo0 = Foo(0, True)
foo1 = Foo(1, False)
foo2 = Foo(2, True)
foo3 = Foo(3, False)
bar = Bar()
bar.append(foo0) # Instance of 'Bar' has no 'append' memberpylint(no-member)
bar.append(foo1) # Instance of 'Bar' has no 'append' memberpylint(no-member)
bar.append(foo2) # Instance of 'Bar' has no 'append' memberpylint(no-member)
bar.append(foo3) # Instance of 'Bar' has no 'append' memberpylint(no-member)

bar.print()
```

It runs just fine and seems to do what it's supposed to do, but Pylint really doesn't seem to like it (error messages in the comments).

Is there a way to make this stop?

Comment: self is not iterable, give it a list

Comment: `List[Foo]` is a type *hint*, not the type `list` itself.

Comment: Ok, but if I use `list` instead, how can I ensure that only foo will be inserted into the list?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will fix all Pylint errors

```
from typing import List
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, _a : int, _b : bool):
        self.a = _a
        self.b = _b

class Bar(List[Foo]):
    def print(self):
        for entry in list(self):
            print(entry.a)
            print(entry.b)

foo0 = Foo(0, True)
foo1 = Foo(1, False)
foo2 = Foo(2, True)
foo3 = Foo(3, False)

bar = Bar([foo0,foo1,foo2,foo3])
bar.print()
```

Comment: Here self is not a list, even though it has all list members(properties), it is a class object of __main__.Bar
and
here class Bar expects List object

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out in comments, `List[Foo]` is not the `list` type, but a *type hint* that certain type checkers (e.g., [`mypy`](http://www.mypy-lang.org/)) will use to analyze your code. The correct usage of type hints is such:

```py
a: List[int] = [1, 2, 3]  # a is a list of ints
b: List[float] = []
b.append(1.0)
b.append("string")  # a type checker would point out that this is an error
```

On the other hand, subclassing the built-in `list` type probably won't give you the desired results. At least in CPython, built-in types like `list` and `dict` have most methods implemented in C for performance reasons, so it's not possible to directly override certain behaviors. Read [this article](https://treyhunner.com/2019/04/why-you-shouldnt-inherit-from-list-and-dict-in-python/) for more details.

However, Python does provide a [`UserList`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList) class that supports inheritance. It basically implements `list` behaviors in pure Python, so it has worse performance, but is more customizable. To only permit objects of certain types to be added to the list, you can just override the `append` method (and `extend` and [`__iadd__`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__) (`+=`) if you want to be complete) and manually do the type checking:

```py
from collections import UserList

class Bar(UserList):
    def append(self, item):
        if not isinstance(item, Foo):
            raise ValueError
        super().append(item)

    def extend(self, items):
        if any(not isinstance(x, Foo) for x in items):
            raise ValueError
        super().extend(items)

    def __iadd__(self, items):
        self.extend(items)
        return self

    def print(self):
        for entry in self:
            print(entry.a)
            print(entry.b)
```

You can verify that, when the following code is run:

```py
foo0 = Foo(0, True)
foo1 = Foo(1, False)
foo2 = Foo(2, True)
foo3 = Foo(3, False)
bar = Bar()
bar.append(foo0)
bar.extend([foo1])
bar += [foo2, foo3]

# Check that exceptions are correctly raised.
try:
    bar.append(None)
except ValueError:
    pass
else:
    print("Exception not raised")
try:
    bar += [foo0, foo1, None]
except ValueError:
    pass
else:
    print("Exception not raised")

bar.print()
```

We'd get:

```
0
True
1
False
2
True
3
False
```